# Laravel Nova + polymorphic Tags: when attaching "no morph map defined"

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have Tags set up in Laravel just like in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) example:

```
// App/Models/MyModel.php

public function tags()
{
   return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
}
```

And I added this to my Nova v3 list of fields, just like in the [Nova documentation](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/relationships.html#morphtomany):

```
// App/Nova/MyModel.php

public function fields(Request $request)
{
  //...
  MorphToMany::make('Tags')
}
```

Existing Tags are shown just fine in Nova, but when I try to attach I get the message:

> No morph map defined for model [App\Models\Tag]. There was a problem
> submitting the form.

When I detach a Tag the error is:

> No morph map defined for model
> [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot]

However, the Tag is detached after all and is gone after refreshing the page.

There is no problem when I manually attach / detach:

```
$myModel->tags()->attach($tag)
```

Suggestions?

**update**: my `AppServiceProvider.php` contains:

```
Relation::enforceMorphMap([
  'myModel' => 'App\Models\MyModel',
]);
```

When I disable this `enforceMorphMap` Nova does not have an issue. But that is unwanted, I don't want to write `App\Models\MyModel` to the DB, but instead only: `myModel`.

I tried adding to the `enforceMorphMap`: `'tag' => 'App\Models\Tag'` (even though that is never written to the DB), but that did not have any effect.

Seems to be related to this [Nova issue](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/3547)?
Unclear what the resolution / workaround is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same issue here... After reading through the doc, I figured it out:

Using `Relation::enforceMorphMap` means, it will toggle the `$requireMorphMap` property on:

```
public static function requireMorphMap($requireMorphMap = true)
    {
        static::$requireMorphMap = $requireMorphMap;
    }
```

then whenever you called the morph relation of Tag instance, it will call `getMorphClass()` where it will check whether `$requireMorphMap` is true via `Relation::requiresMorphMap()`, if it does, exception will be thrown.

```
 public function getMorphClass()
    {
       ...
        if (Relation::requiresMorphMap()) {
            throw new ClassMorphViolationException($this);
        }

        return static::class;
    }
```

Solution:

1/ Add a new key to your `Relation::enforceMorphMap()` with the model that is causing the error.

2/ Replace the call to `Relation::enforceMorphMap()` with `Relation::morphMap()`. This will not require the morph maps anymore for your models.

Inspired by : https://ralphjsmit.com/laravel-fix-no-morph-map-defined

Answer (score 3):

Indeed related to the mentioned [Nova issue](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/3547).
Changing `enforceMorphMap` to `morphMap` works.

```
Relation::morphMap([
  'myModel' => 'App\Models\MyModel',
]);
```